# Passing data from a adapter to fragment using startActivityForResult within same activity

Tags: java, android, fragment, startactivityforresult

I want to pass a data from my adapter class to another fragment with the help of startActivityForResult. If I used the below code same activity recreates it i don't want that. How to solve this issue?

```
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putString(Constants.SELECTED_PLOCATION, pLocation);
mBundle.putString(Constants.SELECTED_RLOCATION, rLocation);
mBundle.putString(Constants.SELECTED_FROM, selectedFrom);
mBundle.putString(Constants.FROM_TYPE, fromType);
mBundle.putString(Constants.AREA_TYPE, Constants.AREA);
getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
Intent mIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), AuthorizedCustomerActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(mIntent, PICK_LOCATION_REQUEST, mBundle);
```

Comment: please specify where is your Adapter class and  Fragment ? In which Activity Fragment Exists And in which Activity Adapter exists

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for data transfer from adapter to fragment;

```
Fragment fragment = new YourFragmentName();
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
ft.commit();

Bundle mBundle= new Bundle();
mBundle.putString(Constants.SELECTED_PLOCATION, pLocation);
mBundle.putString(Constants.SELECTED_RLOCATION, rLocation);
mBundle.putString(Constants.SELECTED_FROM, selectedFrom);
mBundle.putString(Constants.FROM_TYPE, fromType);
mBundle.putString(Constants.AREA_TYPE, Constants.AREA);
fragment.setArguments(mBundle);
```